# Changing date format in R to subtract dates

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

I'm trying to subtract one date from another and then write the output in terms of the number of days. The problem is that the two dates I have are formatted differently -- I've tried to change the formatting, but it doesn't work.

In `df2$Filedate`, dates are formatted as `%Y-%m-%d`, e.g. `2015-01-03`.
In the other column containing dates, `df2$Date`, the formatting is `%y-%m-%d`, e.g. `15-01-01`.

So if I can convert `df2$Filedate` from `%Y-%m-%d` to `%y-%m-%d`, I should be able to subtract dates and write to a new column like this:

```
df2$z <- df2$Filedate - df2$Date
```

This is what I've tried. First, I format:

```
df2$Filedate <- format(df2$Filedate, "%y-%m-%d")
```

The output now looks correct. I convert these strings to dates again, like this:

```
df2$Filedate <- as.Date(df2$Filedate, "%y-%m-%d")
```

And the dates are now, again, formatted as `%Y-%m-%d`!

Comment: You cannot have a "Date" classed object with an abbreviated year.  What's wrong with having the complete year?

Comment: When I subtract df2$Filedate - df2$Date the output is wrong, so I assume that I need both dates to have the same format. Hence I try to change it so both are %y-%m-%d OR both are %Y-%m-%d. In any case the conversion doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's what I did:

```
df2$Filedate <-strftime (df2$Filedate,"%d/%m/%Y")
df2$Date <-strftime(strptime (df2$Date,"%d/%m/%y"),"%d/%m/%Y")

df2$Date <- as.Date (df2$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
df2$Filedate <- as.Date (df2$Filedate, "%d/%m/%Y")

df2$z <- df2$Filedate - df2$Date
```